# Files on USB flash drive inaccessible

Tags: usb-flash-drive, usb-storage

I have a USB flash drive that became inaccessible, with weird file names. I scanned it with different antivirus programs, it's clean but nothing opens. How can I recover my data back?

[image]

Comment: I resized your image just to make it easier for people to read without having to click through to the full image

Comment: How old is this drive? Is it from brand or no-name? Is there important data on it? Do you know if it has been yanked out without using Safe Removal?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure; but maybe that flash drive used to be infected by a ransomware, then it has been disinfected.

Did you plug-in that flash drive to any computer execpt yours before seeing weird named folders? If yes, the situation which I mentioned above is possible.

So, what is "ransomware"?

"Ransomware" is a kind of malware which encrypts files and folders, then threatens the user with data loss if the user does not pay to developer of the malware.

In that situation, you can not trust to the developer; because he/she has bad intent. There is no guarantee for getting back those datas even if you pay.

I mean, the developer is a liar probably.

So, what can you do?

You can download the decryption tool from this website if you know which malware infected that flash drive:

https://noransom.kaspersky.com

PS: Tools which shared in the website which I mentioned above require unencrypted copy of any data which is that flash drive.

Comment: @Andy T. Did you ever read "I'm not sure" sentence? Is ransomware existans impossible in that situation? I have answered this question like that; because op said that "I can not access files/folders". Then I thought maybe those folders are encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

Nah I don't think so. Ransomware install then cleaned...  Too much of a zebra.  I dont think its a virus at all, youre looking the wrong direction.

I think your language encoding is off somewhere.  Your file structure appears intact, as the file attributes are still reading.  I think this should be recoverable.  Not quite sure how though.

Run ChkDsk from the command line on it.

`<!`>Windows Key + R
cmd then press `<!`>Ctrl + Shift + Enter  `o`This will run it as administrator
then from the command prompt, check out the following:

- Chkdsk

  - run this `o`chkdsk `<yourdriveletterhere`>`:  /F
- chknfts
- Compact

  - check to see if it has been compressed and screwed up names like that
- Diskpart

  - opens new window
  - now 'List Disk' find your disk and volume based on size. Then type 'select disk #'
  - and then 'list volume' -> 'select volume #' just like above.  Now weve got it selected.
- now 'details disk' and 'details volume'

  - use help to look around
- USE HELP AND /? LIBERALLY

Comment: I disagree. All information in the screenshot (names, dates) is all over the place. Explorer would be able to open folders, even with encoding issues. This isn’t about text encoding anymore, the filesystem is corrupted.

Comment: Well chkdsk would rapidly pick that up.  And likely repair it. Still doesn’t look like a virus.  It probably got pulled out while updating the file table.  The big question is gonna be, is this exFAT or NFTS. One is much easier to repair than the other.

Comment: and you’re right. The dates are all over the place. I didn’t notice how badly before.

Answer (score 1):

Can you rename the files\folder to something more simple. If it doesn't work form File Explorer (Windows Explorer) try renaming the files\folders form the command prompt.

Comment: Attempting this is not advisable. Making changes to a corrupted filesystem will further exacerbate the corruption, and thus make data recovery a lot harder.